# How can I improve this code?

Tags: python, rounding

```
# max_list = [83, 1350, 1, 100]
for i in range(len(max_list)):
     new_value = 1
     while new_value < max_list[i]:
          new_value *= 10
     max_list = new_value
```

What I'm doing is rounding numbers up to the closest, uhm, zero filled value? I'm not sure what it would be called. But basically, I want 83 -> 100, 1 -> 1, 1350 -> 10000, 100 -> 100. I tried using the round() function but couldn't get it to do what I wanted.

This does it but I thought it could be written in less lines.

Comment: no, i want it to go to 10000. i'll be dividing values by these numbers later. i need it to be 1350 / 10000 = 0.135 so it's in the [0, 1] range.

Comment: You want all the numbers normalized to the same power of ten, right?  You don't need different expressions for the `new_value`, you need two passes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd do it mathematically:

```
from math import ceil, log10
int(pow(10, ceil(log10(abs(x or 0.1)))))
```

Comment: I'd use `pow(10, ceil(abs(log10(x))))` for the case of negative input.

Comment: +1, Look at you, bringing intelligence where everyone else brought string processing :)  And zero is a trivial special case.

Comment: .. and don't forget to import `*` (or at least `pow`, `ceil` and `log10`) from `math` ;)

Comment: `int(pow(10, ceil(log10(abs(x) or 0.1))))` would work better for x < 1

Comment: Good suggestions, added them to the answer.

Comment: @Stephen: str() version is actually a hair (7-8%) faster than the log10() one

Answer (score 3):

```
def nextPowerOfTen(x):
  if x in [0, 1]:
     return x
  elif x < 1:
    return -nextPowerOfTen(abs(x))
  else:
    return 10**len(str(int(x) - 1))

>>> nextPowerOfTen(83)
100
>>> nextPowerOfTen(1350)
10000
>>> nextPowerOfTen(1)
1
>>> nextPowerOfTen(100)
100
>>> nextPowerOfTen(0)
0
>>> nextPowerOfTen(-1)
-1
>>> nextPowerOfTen(-2)
-10
```

It does something sensible with negatives, not sure if that is the behaviour you want or not.

Comment: Fixed failure on powers of 10

Answer (score 1):

> i need it to be 1350 / 10000 = 0.135 so it's in the [0, 1] range.

Why didn't you say so initially?

```
new_val = float("0." + str(old_val))
```

Unless you need the numbers for something else as well?

Comment: you probably want to use float(), not int()

Comment: i'm using floating points too - i forgot to mention it - so i think i'd have to remove the separator. but that looks like it'll work

Comment: Doesn't this fail for 1, `1->0.1` should be `1->1`?

Comment: @Bwmat: Fixed, thanks. @Stephen: Yes, it does. However, [0, 1] is actually kind of a funny range to use - [0, 1) is generally more useful. I'd be interested in seeing how @iceburn intends to use these "normalized" values.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = 12345.678
>>> y = round(x)
>>> round(10 * y, -len(str(y)))
100000
```

Comment: doesn't work for floating points though. i forgot to mention that sorry

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
div = input != 1 ? power(10,truncate(log10(abs(input))) + 1) : 1;
percent = input/div;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code was close, and more easily read than some terse expression.  The problem with your code is a couple of minor errors: initializing `new_value` each time in the initial scan, rather than only once; and replacing the `max_list` with a calculated scalar while looping over it as a list.

On the final line, you must have intended:

```
    max_list[i] = float(max_list[i]) / new_value
```

but you dropped the array index, which would replace the list with a single value.  On the second iteration of the loop, your Python would give an exception due to the invalid index into a non-list.

Because your code develops greater and greater values of new_value as it progresses, I recommend you not replace the list items during the first scan.  Make a second scan once you calculate a final value for new_value:

```
max_list = [83, 1350, 1, 100]

# Calculate the required "normalizing" power-of-ten
new_value = 1.0
for i in range(len(max_list)):
    while new_value < max_list[i]:
        new_value *= 10.0

# Convert the values to fractions in [0.0, 1.0]
for i in range(len(max_list)):
    max_list[i] = max_list[i] / new_value

print max_list
# "[0.0083000000000000001, 0.13500000000000001, 0.0001, 0.01]"
```

Notice that I was required to initialize new_value as if it were a floating-point value, in order that it would result in floating-point quotients.  There are alternative ways to do this, such as using `float(max_list[i])` to retrieve the value for normalizing.  The original calculation of `new_value` was starting over with each element, so your example would return `new_value == 100` because this was based off the final element in the input list, which is 100.

Comment: max_list has the maximum of each column in a file. after changing the values i then divide each element for its respective maximum, eg if the first line in my file is: 10, 10, 20, 30 and my maximums are 10, 100, 100, 1000 i'll have 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.03 as the new first line. the code i posted only shows one part of what i'm doing, which is taking the maximums and rounding them

Comment: In that case, the only thing wrong with your original code is the "final line" comment I made.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import ceil, log10

# works for floats, too.
x = [83, 1350, 1, 100, 12.75]
y = [10**ceil(log10(el)) for el in x]

# alt list-comprehension if integers needed
# y = [int(10**ceil(log10(el))) for el in x]
```